# auto complete for Qt in emacs

Tags: qt, emacs, autocomplete, qt4

I have become addicted to emacs and have been using it for everything. Now, I have started Qt4 . I am forced to move to the Qt Creator because of its auto complete feature which is required when writing programs in Qt because of the heavy use of pr edefined functions in it.

But the problem is that I don't want to leave emacs. Is there any way to get a auto-complete feature close to that of Qt Creator in emacs.

I have installed the CEDET-1.1 where I discovered the text file for c++ which contains all the commonly used c++ keywords. One way could be to add Qt class and function names in that file which gives me a pretty basic auto complete for Qt. But can I get a better auto complete?

Comment: You have to consider, do you want to develop emacs, or do you want to develop Qt applications. If latter, use existing IDE and learn it

Comment: @hyde  If "something is worth doing, it's worth doing well," it then follows that if something is worth doing, it can be done in emacs.

Comment: @Dmitri Emacs lisp is a turing complete language with file system access, so obviously anything can be done... Has it been done already by somebody else, and done well too, is another matter... There are some C++ parsers for emacs, but are they good enough to parse Qt headers to provide syntax highlighting and autocompletion, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use cedet anymore, it is big, and slow.

I recommand you use https://github.com/brianjcj/auto-complete-clang, which is lightweight, and much easy to use. All you need to do is to learn and configure of auto-complete and yasnippet.